# How to using onclick to call function and play video in iframe/video tag on 1 click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

How to using onclick to call function and play video in iframe/video tag on 1 click ?

https://jsfiddle.net/v9j1dqbw/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/ofqm0o5n/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/0b9L6fL9/2/

```
<script>
function check_view_for_update_fn() 
{
    alert("test");
    document.getElementById("video_upper_div").remove();
    // play video //
}
</script>
```

When click on id `video_upper_div` it's will call function `check_view_for_update_fn` and then it's will be `alert` and remove element id `video_upper_div` i want to play video after remove element id `video_upper_div` using javascript, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want this

```
    function check_view_for_update_fn(){
    alert("test");
    document.getElementById("video_upper_div").remove();
    document.getElementById("video").src += "?rel=0&autoplay=1";
    // play video //
    }
```